# Using a Visual Sourcesafe 2005 database with VB6 still launches VSS 6.0d

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, visual-sourcesafe, visual-sourcesafe-2005

I know all versions of VSS have many horror stories and I feel I will escape to a better source control mechanism someday but in the short term I am just trying to do a little cleanup and would like your advice on this issue:

**Objective** - consolidate old VB6 source code in a "new" VSS 2005 database (currently all these old projects are checked in to an "old" VSS 6.0d database); eventually, eliminate the "old" VSS.

**Progress so far** - The new VSS 2005 database now contains a mixture of projects. Some are using Visual Studio 2008, some use Vstudio 2005, and the more recently added ones are the above mentioned VB6 projects. Individually all these projects and "solutions" come up OK, I can check in - check out, launch SourceSafe, view differences, etc.

But all the VB6 projects now in a VSS 2005 database launch VSS 6.0d when asked, rather than VSS 2005.

Is this normal and just something to cope with until I get to some better nonVSS approach? Or can VB6 be re-configured someway to launch VSS 2005 when I click Tools->SourceSafe->Run SourceSafe? I seem to recall VSS 6.0d got "integrated" into VB6 by way of the "Add-In Manager". At this point, the development PC with VB6 installed has both VSS 2005 and VSS 6.0d clients installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going from memory, you need to try the following :

Look for a file in the folder where you have the SourceSafe client installed called ssint.exe. Copy this to where SourceSafe 2005 is installed, then run it. This should make Visual Studio load SourceSafe 2005 now. 2005 does not integrate with Visual Studio 6 as part of its installation.
Update :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbinterop/thread/86496254-2b17-4b7b-9134-00275fc4df77

Comment: Beautiful. Your suggestion seemed more clear and safer so I did exactly as you said and now the VB6 IDE integrates with VSS 2005. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

VSS 2005 did not change the database format.  In fact you are able to open a VSS 6.0 db with VSS 2005 just fine.  The installation of the binaries reside in different locations and side by side installations are fine, you just need to make sure that the path settings on your computer (as well as any settings for Version Control in visual studio) are set to point to the proper version of VSS.

You can open up a copy of VSS2005 and then point it to your original VSS 6.0 database and just start going without any "migration" required.

The default paths for VSS 2005 installation and VSS 6.0 are different as follows:

VSS 6.0: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\VSS\win32

VSS 2005: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual SourceSafe

I would check the paths of the executables and be sure that you are pointing to the correct one.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't aware you could install VSS 6.0D and VSS 2005 on the same machine.

Uninstall VSS 6.0D and re-install VSS 2005.